# Lighting change when baking

Tags: baking

As far as I know, you can only bake non reflective materials in Cycles. If I had a scene and I wanted to bake the non reflective parts to speed up an animation render time, I would still have to keep the lighting for the reflective materials. By keeping the lighting, it lights up the baked materials so that they appear brighter than they were oriiginally intended to be. What can be done to make the lighting appear exactly the materials were changed? (Besides guessing and checking with the emission energy values on the baked materials.)

Comment: If you're using an emission shader for the baked materials, the lighting shouldn't affect them..?

Comment: Last time I did a test on it, the lights still did, but that was without baked materials...